# ASP.NET MVC Url.Action creating Get not Post

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have:

```
public ActionResult Create(Guid appId)
{
    var vm = new CreateViewModel(appId);

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel vm)
{
    // this does some stuff
}
```

Now, in the View I use this for creating the Form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

Standard.

How ever, it produces the wrong HTML:

```
<form action="/SomeController/Create?appId=414FDS-45F2SF-TEF234">
```

This is not what I want posted back, I don't want `appId` what so ever. Just the `Create`

How do you get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use another overload of `Html.BeginForm` to explicitly specify the action you want:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "SomeController"))
{

}
```

This will not append anything to the URL by default.

Comment: Okay, so this won't add that get request on then

Comment: @No1_Melman, no, it will generate just `/SomeController/Create`.

Comment: Problem, I'm still getting _no parameterless constructor defined for this object_ .... do I have to put `appId` in the constructor?

Comment: @No1_Melman, context? On which line are you getting this message, for what object?

Comment: Nope, its fine, the `ViewModel` i was passing back to the `Action` had no parameterless constructor, so I created one and it works :)